# Android Game loop using a thread postdelayed()

Tags: android, frame-rate, postdelayed, game-loop

I thought I was being clever using this code for the game thread loop, instead of the usual `while(running)` loop:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "+ run()");
        final long [] old = new long [] { System.currentTimeMillis() };
        Log.w(TAG,"Start time=" + old[0]);

        Thread loop = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if( running ) {
                    Canvas canvas = null;
                    try {
                        canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.w(TAG,"Loop time=" + t + ", delta=" + (t-old[0]));
                        old[0] = t;
                        synchronized( mSurfaceHolder ) {
                            mGame.update();
                            mGame.onDraw(canvas);
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        // Do this in finally so that if an exception is thrown
                        // we don't leave the Surface in an inconsistent state
                        if( canvas != null ) {
                            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Posting thread with delay " + interval + " milliseconds");
                    handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
                }
            };
        };
        Log.i(TAG, "Posting thread with no delay");
        handler.post(loop);
        Log.d(TAG, "- run()");
    }
```

The first thread is posted, then each thread posts itself back into the queue with a given delay.

Which produced this log (partial) :

```
03-09 12:51:22.665: D/GameLoop(3116): + run()
03-09 12:51:22.665: W/GameLoop(3116): Start time=1362826282665
03-09 12:51:22.665: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with no delay
03-09 12:51:22.665: D/GameLoop(3116): - run()
03-09 12:51:22.687: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826282691, delta=26
03-09 12:51:22.687: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:22.687: D/GameView(3116): + onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus:true)
03-09 12:51:22.687: D/GameLoop(3116): + resume()
03-09 12:51:22.687: D/GameLoop(3116): - resume()
03-09 12:51:22.687: D/GameView(3116): - onWindowFocusChanged()
03-09 12:51:22.745: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826282745, delta=54
03-09 12:51:22.745: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.284: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283284, delta=539
03-09 12:51:23.285: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.366: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283367, delta=83
03-09 12:51:23.366: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.425: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283426, delta=59
03-09 12:51:23.425: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.495: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283504, delta=78
03-09 12:51:23.505: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.555: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283561, delta=57
03-09 12:51:23.555: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.615: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283622, delta=61
03-09 12:51:23.615: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.675: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283675, delta=53
03-09 12:51:23.686: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.749: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283750, delta=75
03-09 12:51:23.749: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.807: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283808, delta=58
03-09 12:51:23.807: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.875: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283884, delta=76
03-09 12:51:23.875: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:23.936: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826283938, delta=54
03-09 12:51:23.946: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:24.006: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826284006, delta=68
03-09 12:51:24.006: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:24.065: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826284065, delta=59
03-09 12:51:24.065: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
03-09 12:51:24.126: W/GameLoop(3116): Loop time=1362826284126, delta=61
03-09 12:51:24.126: I/GameLoop(3116): Posting thread with delay 50 milliseconds
```

I know postdelay is not accurate, but here every single time it runs late than the required 50 milli.
My `mGame.update()` method is empty right now, and `mGame.onDraw()` draws 2 rectangles, one line and one text. I consider it not to be particularly heavy, and still it cannot keep up with 20FPS.

How do they render those graphic intensive games like asphalt and keep up a high FPS?

Caveat: This runs in an emulator running Intel's HAXM engine, which is as fast as an emulator can get.

To be clear about what I'm asking, it is:

**What do I have to do to achieve high FPS in a (not computational heavy) game loop?**

Note: I know the postdelayed will be at least 50 milli. But two things bother me, always, the second call takes several hundreds milli, and the accuracy varies from 20 to 10 FPS and I am worried the movement on screen will not look uniform.

**Edit**
Just to test I reduced the interval to 20 milli (50FPS) and the delta remained in the range 50-70 milli (emulator).
I increased th einterval to 83 milli (12FPS) and the delta was 87-93 (emulator).
I installed the app in an ASUS TF201 running Nvidia quadcore and the delta did not change much.

The conclusion is that for games using Canvas and update-draw loops I cannot go up from 20FPS. Dissapointing.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are using OpenGL instead Canvas

Why are you using synchronize in

```
synchronized( mSurfaceHolder )
```

Comment: I use synchronize to ensure this is the only code touching the SurfaceView. ::: The majority of game loop examples in the web use a `while()` loop with `synchronize()` body, when I changed my code I left it there because I am not really sure what other threads are running in the system and might try to access the same SurfaceView (for example garbage collection (?))

Comment: by `canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);` only this thread can modify this canvas

Comment: I dont think so. You won't achieve good performance using canvas. Use OpenGL instead

Answer (score 0):

dude, i use canvas and get 15ms frames, 1 to 4 ms lag, with 200 sprites all bitmap drawn to a synchronized canvas. not sure what your deal is, but i just looked at the lunarlander api demo a year ago, and it's been all gravy from there. one line in manifest enables hardware acceleration,  and forget emulators working with anything you need to be fast and graphical. i won't lie and say it's the easiest platform for game dev(it's about the worst IMO), but give it some time, you'll figure it out.